# Zimbra upgrade fails: Perl API version v5.14.0 of Socket does not match v5.18.0

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, zimbra

I just tried to upgrade my Zimbra version from 8.0.5 to 8.7 after I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.
I followed this guide: https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Upgrades but I still got this error: Perl API version v5.14.0 of Socket does not match v5.18.0
And did the following steps (just to reproduce:

1. stopping zimbra (zmcontrol stop as zimbra)
2. updating and upgrading all existing packages: apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
3. Ubuntu Release Upgrade (as disclaimed in the Wiki I always chose the default option, aka kept the original configurations)
4. Checking Ubuntu version: Linux version 3.13.0-95-generic (buildd@lgw01-58) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 17:00:09 UTC 2016
5. Reboot, apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, another rebboot (just to be save)
6. Downloading and unpacking zimbra 8.7 for Ubuntu 14.04 (packagename: zcs-8.7.0_GA_1659.UBUNTU14_64.20160628202701.tgz)
7. installing PERL 5.18: apt-get install libperl5.18
8. ./install.sh -s

After the last step I get the following output:

```
root@mail:~/zcs-8.7.0_GA_1659.UBUNTU14_64.20160628202701# ./install.sh -s

Operations logged to /tmp/install.log.H0RNHBEX
Checking for existing installation...
    zimbra-ldap...FOUND zimbra-ldap-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-logger...FOUND zimbra-logger-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-mta...FOUND zimbra-mta-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-dnscache...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-snmp...FOUND zimbra-snmp-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-store...FOUND zimbra-store-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-apache...FOUND zimbra-apache-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-spell...FOUND zimbra-spell-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-convertd...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-memcached...FOUND zimbra-memcached-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-proxy...FOUND zimbra-proxy-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
    zimbra-archiving...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-core...FOUND zimbra-core-8.0.5.GA.5839.UBUNTU12.64
ZCS upgrade from 8.0.5 to 8.7.0 will be performed.
Checking for existing proxy service in your environment
Perl API version v5.14.0 of Socket does not match v5.18.0 at /usr/share/perl/5.18/XSLoader.pm line 92.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/zimbra/zimbramon/lib/Net/LDAP.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/zimbra/zimbramon/lib/Net/LDAP.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at bin/checkService.pl line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bin/checkService.pl line 21.
Error: Unable to contact the LDAP server.
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have a LVM-snapshot and a complete backup though, but really wanted to upgrade because of a bunch of security upgrades.